# Combining multiple GIT repositories while preserving all tags/branches

Tags: git

I already managed to merge branches from multiple GIT repositories into a single new repository (using a combination of "git filter-branch" and "git fetch/merge"). But I cannot seem to "merge" the tags from those branches...is this even possible ? As far as my (quite limited) GIT knownledge goes, a tag refers to a single commit that itself is identified by a SHA1 hash value that is basically calculated from all preceeding commits. Since branches from different repositories don't have a common ancestor commit, I find it hard to image how a tag could be rewritten in a way that it still "makes sense" (in the GIT way) in the context of a new and totally unrelated repository.

Any ideas ?

EDIT: To clarify what I intend to do:

Let's assume I have two repositories called "A" and "B" that I want to combine into a single new repository called "C".

The directory layout is something like

```
A
|
|-someFileA
|-anotherFileA
|-...
```

```
B
|
|-someFileB
|-anotherFileB
|-...
```

and the combined repository should look like

```
C
|
|-A
| |-someFileA
| |-anotherFileA
| |-...
|
|-B
| |-someFileB
| |-anotherFileB
| |-...
```

Comment: how are the repositories related, in terms of file structure and history? I mean what do they share?

Comment: The two repositories share nothing (one repository holds SQL to setup a database (schema, stored procedures etc.) , the other repository holds the Java application that will later access this database. Since the Java code depends on a specific version of the database schema, it makes sense to combine both repositories so that it's possible to create a tag across both modules.

Comment: I think that in order for any answer to be more complete, you need to (completely) define what you want the *history* to look like. You can just do a couple of subtree merges and be done, and have completely disjoint history for A and B, but I suspect you're looking for some sort of interleaving?

Answer (score 2):

Tags are not directories (as they would in Subversion), so fetch/merge won't consider them.
Plus a git fetch doesn't fetch all tags by default (unless `--tags` is specified).

Considering tags reference an immutable content, and that you are modifying that content through merges, I don't think you can easily preserve them, unless you reapply tags with similar name manually to commits that you deem similar to the original tagged ones.

---

Another less intrusive way to "combine" those two repos would be to declare `A` and `B` as [submodules of `C`](http://%60).
No merge involved, and `A` and `B` keep theirs branches and tags

Comment: Hnm, that's what I already suspected...maybe I should rephrase my question and ask for a solution to reapply those tags :)

Comment: Since I want to combine my repositories (among other things) in order to be able to create a tag across all modules, GIT submodules will not help here (because creating tags across modules is not supported).

Comment: @JavaGuy: creating tags across modules is not supported? Why yes, they are... in a way. When you are tagging the parent repo, you are tagging the reference to the exact commits of the submodules currently referenced by said parent repo. Even if the submodules themselves don't know about that tag, you can get the precise commit of both repos by selecting the right tag of the parent repo.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to waste a few hours on it, I did some similar weird repo management through python and [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/).  It's a one off hack, but if getting it done is worth a few hours or time, go for it.